# If $P \iff Q,¬Q$ are proved, what are the inference schemes following from them?

Tags: propositional-calculus

I'm reading Exner's *Logic in Elementary Mathematics*, there is an exercise in which I should point all the inference schemes, if any in a bunch of statements. There is this one:

> A point $P$ is called the *pole* of a line $p$ iff $P$ is not joined to any point on $p$ by a line.
>
> $P$ is joined to a point on $p$ by a line.
>
> $\therefore$ $P$ is not the pole of $p$.

I am a little confused at how should I do it. I guess that it would be the contrapositive inference:

$$\cfrac{P\rightarrow Q, ¬Q}{¬P}$$

Now:

$P'$ : A point $P$ is called the *pole* of a line $p$.

$Q'$ :  $P$ is not joined to any point on $p$ by a line.

$$\cfrac{P'\rightarrow Q', ¬Q'}{¬P'}$$

I pointed the inference scheme for:

I guess I pointed out the scheme inference for $\rightarrow $, now should I do it for $\leftarrow$? I'm a little bit confused at what it would became, is it?

$$\cfrac{Q'\rightarrow P', ¬P'}{¬Q'}$$

---

Also: In my previous attempts, I tried to do the following:

$P'$ : A point $P$ is called the *pole* of a line $p$.

$Q'$ :  $P$ is joined to any point on $p$ by a line. *(Notice the absence of not)*

And hence I would have something different:

$$\cfrac{P'\rightarrow ¬Q', Q'}{¬P'}$$

I would have to *negate* $Q'$ here but it gives a completely different thing which I'm not truly sure is the same, but I think are not, based on experimentation with truth tables. So, should I always pick *"convenient"* variables for the job?

Comment: 2nd premise : "$P$ is joined to a point $p$ by a line" or "$P$ is joined to a point **on** $p$ by a line" ? In the first case $p$ is a *point*; in the second case it is a *line*.

Comment: If my correction is the right one, we have $A \leftrightarrow B$ and $\lnot B$; therefore : $\lnot A$.

Comment: The issue is with "formalization" (in that case, you need predicate logic) or with *inference* ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA In the second case, it is a line, no? Any point on $p$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  The exercise is [this](http://imgur.com/a/07WPo).

Comment: Nevermind, I understand now.